# In an algebraic system, is there a general name for an element that behaves like 0 does for multiplication in $\mathbb R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, terminology

In an algebraic system, an element  that behaves like $0$ does for addition or like 1 does for multiplication of real numbers is called an " identity element" ;  an element that is to some element $a$ like $\frac 12$ is  to 2 is called an inverse element of $a$.

Is there a general name for an element that behaves like $0$ does for multiplication?

I mean, a general  name  for an element $n$ having this property :  $ \forall(a) a * n = n*a=n$ , $*$ being a binary operation?

Comment: We have $0\cdot a=a\cdot 0=0$ for all $a\in R$. "0" is just the null-element of the ring R.

Comment: If you are assuming a ring or a field the only such element is the additive identity and it is just called "$0$"  (As by distribution $0\times a = (0+0)\times a = 0\times a + 0\times a$ so $0\times a$ must but equal to $0$. And it is unique as $n=n*a=n*(a+a)=n*a+n*a=n+n$ so $n=0$.)  But for abstract structures that need not be rings or fields then .... Well, Ben Steffan answer has the word for it.

Comment: @Peter Well, to be fair the OP never stated we were working with a Ring.  S/he wanted the name for such an element with *any* binary operation on a set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, such an element is known as an [absorbing element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_element).

Comment: the name is properly given!

Comment: Please search first before posting yet more dupe answers to FAQs.